# Java validating a range of numbers from user input

Tags: java, validation, input

I have been having problem with my validation, and it is stressing me out, I have done it in various ways with different loops, and the one I have as of now is this one, if I take out the IF statement if will function well for numbers, but since my program can only accept numbers from 1 to 5 I want to take the extra step into validating the number and then returning it. I try declaring the int option inside a loop but does not carry out to the return statement.

```
    public int makeOption(){
    int option;
    System.out.println("Choose from the following options: ");
    System.out.println("(1)Create entry || (2)Remove entry || (3)List entry || (4)List All || (5)Exit ");

    while(!reader.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Choose a valid option.");
            reader.next();
    }
    if(reader.nextInt()<1 || reader.nextInt()>5){
        System.out.println("Choose a valid number from options.");
        reader.next();
    }
    option = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You choosed: " + option);
    return option;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Swap out your if statement for a switch statement:

```
int input = reader.nextInt();

switch(input)
{
    case 1: // Do something 
          break;
    // blah blah blah more cases.

    default: System.out.println("Please enter a correct value.");
}
```

**A note on your code**

When you call `reader.nextInt()`, you're telling the stream to expect another `int`. You're not viewing the same value. You should store it in a variable, before using it.

Comment: I think the **A note on your code** is the most important point here. @Andrey : in your if-statement-block `if(reader.nextInt()<1 || reader.nextInt()>5){ ...` you are reading three **different** tokens from the input. The two `.nextInt()` calls each read an int and then advance past what was read, then the `.next()` in the body reads and discards *another* token.

Comment: I declared option at the top of the if statement to validate and then on the bottom of the if statement to get the fresh int that passed validation, thanks Chris and Stephen (:

Comment: this did it for me, as you and stephen said I was reading too many integers, and not declaring option to validate just one.